# linux paste column to other file

Tags: bash

I have many files named 0.250, 0.252, 0.254 .... and each file contains some numbers, like

```
0.2520 0.2520 0.2520
0.2520 0.2520 0.7440
0.2520 0.7440 0.2520
0.7440 0.2520 0.2520
```

and I want to paste a column

```
1
2
3
4
```

to each file, so my files 0.250, 0.252 .. to be modified as

```
1 0.2520 0.2520 0.2520
2 0.2520 0.2520 0.7440
3 0.2520 0.7440 0.2520
4 0.7440 0.2520 0.2520
```

I tried paste command, but this doesn't change the actual file..

Comment: paste into a temp file and then move it.`paste file{,2} >tmp && mv tmp file`

Comment: Are you trying to do `nl < input.file`?  (`nl` will prepend line numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
for file in *; do
  nl "$file" > "$file.numbered"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the output of the paste command to a file...

```
paste file1 file2 > outputfile
```

Consider creating new files, and then removing the old ones instead of replacing them on the spot. It is much much safer...

Answer (score 1):

Use `nl` to number lines.

```
nl -s' ' -ba -nln -w1 < input > output
```

Comment: @JID: `-n, --number-format=FORMAT`, `ln     left justified, no leading zeros`

Comment: Oh yeah, its not in my man page for some reason but its on the internet one. Cheers :)